# Online WYSIWYG website builder

Tags: web-apps, web-development, wysiwyg

I am looking for a free (open source) or low cost WYSIWYG website builder that I can host on my own server.  It needs to be able to handle multiple separate sites on different domains, and it needs to be usable by a non-programmer while preferably also allowing direct code editing for more advanced users.

In effect, I'm trying to host my own copy of Wix.com / Squarespace / Weebly for a bunch of local organizations to which I provide tech support.

I already know about [Ghost](https://ghost.org), but the people who will be working on these sites will just be confused by Markdown.

Comment: Have you heard about Wikis?  Like Wikipedia?  Compare a bunch of them at wikimatrix.com and see iif any meet your needs.

Comment: @cybernard Yes, I have certainly heard about Wikis, and I have already looked at a large number of them.  I have not found any that meets my needs.  There are extremely few that have a WYSIWYG interface that the non-technical content managers can use, and there are also very few that are multi-site ready. Also, the website you link to is a parking page, not a real site.

Comment: Apologies it is really http://www.wikimatrix.org/   I made a ".com" assumption and failed.  :(

Comment: @cybernard I had a look at WIkiMatrix, and found nothing there that fills all my requirements.  In addition, I also found that there are a large number of factual errors on the site - features that it claims some wikis have that they actually do not have.

Comment: Some Wiki's have externsion or plugins.  You may find other users have created some of these.  Otherwise, you could pick a wiki that comes the closest and supports plugins.  Write your own plugins, which maybe or may not be a viable option.  Maybe, your advanced user can help you with that.

Comment: @cybernard That's certainly an option on the table - I am perfectly capable of writing my own plugins (or my own software from scratch), but I'm hoping someone will suggest something that's a bit closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to find many software really free in this category.
You could give a try to [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) (open-source but some extension needs to be paid).

Answer (score -2):

Ghost sounds like a pretty good option along with most modernized WYSIWYG sites. I was use to using Square Space, however their templates are limited and it costs extra than basic to edit further into the CSS. Have you tried [Sitelio](https://www.sitelio.com) ?
Stella offers free Ad Credits. It would count as a low cost WYSIWYG website builder but is user friendly. I do not like that it is $3 higher a month to maintain. Much like most WYSIWYG sites, you have to upgrade a decent amount to get the full benefits, the problem that I have run into as well with WYSIWYG sites is that once a client stops paying for it or can not make a payment the site is of course offline almost immediately (hosting). I have not tried Ghost personally. The problem comes when you are looking for a user friendly webbly that can be understood while having the advanced functionality for technical users. I am not sure they have WYSIWYG sites for both types yet.

Comment: Do you have experience with Sitelio? Is there anything you like/dislike about it?

Comment: @Eric How about adding more links to your post and some reasons why you recommend Ghost and Sitelio?

Comment: I already explained why I can't use Ghost - it doesn't have a full WYSIWYG editor - it requires you to know Markdown. Sitelio is also out because you can't host it yourself, which was one of my requirements.